# Subclass ES6 Proxied Class

Tags: javascript, es6-class, es6-proxy

I want to Subclass a `Proxied` ES6 Class. It works just fine in Firefox and Chrome, but Safari 10 throws an error:

```
let SuperClass = class {
    constructor() {
        console.log('SuperClass constructor')
    }
}

let ProxiedSuperClass = new Proxy(SuperClass, {});

let SubClass = class extends ProxiedSuperClass {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log('SubClass constructor')
    }
}

var s = new SubClass(); 

// Expected output (Firefox, Chrome): 
// SuperClass constructor
// SubClass constructor

// Safari output:
// function is not a constructor (evaluating 'super()')
```

So, Safari seems to try to extend `Proxy`, while Firefox and Chrome extend `SuperClass`.

What's the correct behaviour here? Is it just not possible (or well defined) to proxy a Class? Or can I somehow hint Safari to do "the right thing", i.e. to subclass `SuperClass` instead of `Proxy`?

Comment: When you proxy a class, you're really only registering traps on that constructor function and any properties directly defined on it.  The new (class) function still has its original constructor and prototype chain.

Comment: That's what I thought - the proxy should behave like the original object, unless you register traps that do something else. So I guess I should file a bug report with Webkit then?

Comment: I think so - might be worth waiting for other answers, though.  I've never used `Proxy` myself, but the Firefox and Chrome behaviour sounds correct to me.